# The parameter's value don't display with TS

Tags: react-typescript

Goal:
Display the parameter's value in the webpage when you click on the text "DetailView"

Problem:
The value don't display and I am not sure if this tis the correct error for this case.

"The 'jsxFragmentFactory' compiler option must be provided to use JSX fragments with the 'jsxFactory' compiler option.(17016)"

How should I solve it?

Thank you!

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-typescript-example-asrnpk?

Other info:
*Newbie in react TS

```
----------------------------

import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Home, Foo, Bar } from './Pages';
import DetailView from './DetailView';
import './style.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <br />
            <Link to="/foo">Foo</Link>
            <br />
            <Link to="/bar">Bar</Link>
            <br />
            <Link to="/detailview/3}">DetailView</Link>
          </nav>

          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/foo" element={<Foo />} />
            <Route path="/bar" element={<Bar />} />
            <Route path="/detailview/:p1?" element={<DetailView />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));


----------------


import React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface MatchParams {
  id: string;
}

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<MatchParams> {
  // ...
}

const DetailView: React.FC<Props> = ({ match }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const params = match.params;
  return <>{`Test "${params.id}"`}</>;
};

export default DetailView;



-------------------


import React from 'react';

export const Home = () => <h1>Home Page</h1>;
export const Foo = () => <h1>Foo Page</h1>;
export const Bar = () => <h1>Bar Page</h1>;
```

Comment: Also stuck on this. Has something to do with https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#jsxFragmentFactory